# wordpress ajax return 0 as response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

wordpress ajax return 0 as response ,checked with die(); and wp_die(); but still getting 0 as response.

when using both die() and wp_die() result is 0 . can any one help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#profile_form').on("submit", function(e){
        //console.log("here");
        var User_ids = <?php echo $user_ID ?>;
        //console.log(User_ids);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
            data: {
              action: "get_percentage",
              User_ids: User_ids
          },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

```php
add_action("wp_ajax_get_percentage", "get_percentage");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_percentage", "get_percentage");
function get_percentage(){

$user_ID = $_REQUEST['User_ids'];

echo $user;

 wp_die(); 
}
```

Comment: use the network monitor to test if the AJAX call works, e.g. with firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: Also check your debug.log file for any errors.

Comment: Please check console.log your data is sending in User_ids ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_send_json($data);
```

You don't send a reply